# Angular Error in material snackbar

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my angular 4 project I have implemented some [MatSnackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview)
to show some usefull messate to the user.
All snackbars work good except in one case...

When the user try to access to the application but the token has expired my authentication guard redirect the user to the login page and show a snackbar,
this snackbar seems works well but at the console I can see this error:

> MatSnackBarContainer_Host.html:1 ERROR Error:
>   ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value:
>   'visible-bottom'. It seems like the view has been created after its
>   parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created
>   in a change detection hook ?
>       at viewDebugError (core.es5.js:8434) [angular]
>       at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.es5.js:8412) [angular]
>       at checkBindingNoChanges (core.es5.js:8576) [angular]
>       at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.es5.js:12455) [angular]
>       at checkNoChangesNode (core.es5.js:12429) [angular]
>       at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.es5.js:13209) [angular]
>       at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.es5.js:13149) [angular]
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (MatSnackBarContainer_Host.html:1) [angular]
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js:13131) [angular]
>       at checkNoChangesView (core.es5.js:12251) [angular]
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13493) [angular]
>       at Object.debugCheckNoChangesView [as checkNoChangesView] (core.es5.js:13040) [angular]
>       at ViewRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ViewRef_.checkNoChanges
>   (core.es5.js:10197) [angular]
>       at vendor.bundle.js:92838:67 [angular] View_MatSnackBarContainer_Host_0 @ MatSnackBarContainer_Host.html:1
>   MatSnackBarContainer_Host.html:1 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_

In the ngOnInit of the login page I show the snackbar:

```
ngOnInit() {


    if (this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl']) {
      this.openSnackBar(('token expired'));
    }
}
```

-

```
openSnackBar(message: string, action?: string) {
    return this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
      duration: 3000,
    });
  }
```

How can I solve this error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a Material issue : this is a **lifecycle issue**.

In case you don't know, Angular follows a lifecycle in which he checks for changes, assign variables, and so on.

In your case, he is telling you that you changed the value of a variable just after he marked it as checked, and it's messign with him. You can see the new value right there in the error :

```
visible-bottom
```

This means that somewhere in your code, your doing a

```
this.myVar = 'visible-bottom';
```

To correct this error, simply surround it in a timeout like so

```
setTimeout(() => this.myVar = 'visible-bottom');
```

This will tell Angular

> I know you have checked my variable, but I need to change its value, so restart your change detection please

Comment: You could also use the https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef to manually trigger the detectChanges()

Comment: I agree, but the timeout prevents another dependency injection, is shorter to write, and is probably lighter than calling detectChanges() (opinion based comment)

Comment: @trichetriche actually I don't do `this.myVar = 'visible-bottom';`, possible that is the default snackbar?

Comment: Use a Ctrl + Maj + F to find it, or it might come from a back-end call, but I'm not making this up, your error does come from that.

Comment: Now I see if I `setTimeout(() => this.openSnackBar(('token expired')))` I don't have errors

Comment: the `visible-bottom` might be a toaster configuration then. Glad it worked for you !